# Weird Highlighted Cursor VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode seems to have a weird highlight cursor that disables me from typing until I spam a bunch of random keys, where it then returns to normal. How can I fix this weird cursor issue? For reference, the photo below me is what I see, except the highlighted cursor also flashes like a regular one.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBXbg.png)

Comment: Are you using the [VS Code Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension? Try pressing the `i` button on your keyboard to see whether this "weird highlight cursor" turns into normal cursor

Comment: @AnsonH That was the issue!! Thanks for the fix :)

Comment: Awesome! Consider disabling the extension if you are not intended to use it